# How to delete label above bar chart in R that's already in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

this is my first post!

Just wondering how to remove these titles above the charts:

[image]

Here's the code for the diagram!

I imagine I'll have to use something like:
p + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

```
ggplot(data=bike_data_v4)+
      geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=day_of_week,fill=member_casual))+
      scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"),
                       labels = c("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"))+ #the discrete lines show how I rearranges the x-axis labels to go from sun-sat and be renamed to shorter text
      facet_wrap(~member_casual)+
      labs(title="Weekly Rider Differences by Cyclist Type", subtitle="Members vs. Casual Riders",
           x = "Day of the Week",
           y = "Number of Overall Rides",
           caption="Data Provided by Google Capstone Project")+
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500000), labels = scales::comma)+ #this combined scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500000)  AND scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
      theme_fivethirtyeight()+
      labs(fill='Rider Type')+
      theme(axis.title = element_text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `strip.text` option.

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species) + 
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think the "theme_fivethirtyeight" syntax was reintroducing a new label title even after "theme(strip.text = element_blank())". I think I'll have to just do without that theme in order to prevent duplicate info!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the code at the very bottom! ADDED strip.text = element_blank())

Now the bar chart looks like this:[image]

```
ggplot(data=bike_data_v4)+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=day_of_week,fill=member_casual))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"),
                   labels = c("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"))+ #the discrete lines show how I rearranges the x-axis labels to go from sun-sat and be renamed to shorter text
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)+ 
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())+
  labs(title="Weekly Rider Differences by Cyclist Type", subtitle="Members vs. Casual Riders",
       x = "Day of the Week",
       y = "Number of Overall Rides",
       caption="Data Provided by Google Capstone Project")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500000), labels = scales::comma)+ #this combined scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500000)  AND scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
  theme_fivethirtyeight(base_size = 12, base_family = "sans")+
  labs(fill='Rider Type')+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

Comment: Yes, it's cumulative, so always put any `theme()` adjustments to a particular overall theme right at the end. Although to be honest I think you should keep the facet labels and remove the color labels with `labs(color = "none")` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to try that out

Comment: Sorry I meant to say `guides(color = "none")` not `labs()`